# Multiple if conditions with swipe events

Tags: android, android-studio, if-statement, swipe

I'm currently working on a school project in Android Studio and so far I've written a code which generates a random equation. Now I want to display two equations and the user has to decide which of these two has a bigger result. The user then has to do a swipemotion up if the second equation is bigger and a swipemotion down if the second equation is smaller.
Here is the code for the random equations:

```
String[] operationSet = new String[]{"+", "-", "/", "*"};
String stringResultOfEquation;
String equation;
double doubleAnswer1;
public void start1() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int numOfOperations = random.nextInt(2) + 1;

    List<String> operations = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfOperations; i++) {
        String operation = operationSet[random.nextInt(4)];
        operations.add(operation);
    }

    int numOfNumbers = numOfOperations + 1;
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfNumbers; i++) {
        int number = random.nextInt(10)+1;
        numbers.add(number);
    }

    String equation = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfOperations; i++) {
        equation += numbers.get(i);
        equation += operations.get(i);
    }
    equation += numbers.get(numbers.size() -1);

    TextView TextEquation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextEquation.setText(equation);

    String stringResultOfEquation = String.valueOf(equation);

    double doubleAnswer1 = eval(stringResultOfEquation);

    String stringAnswer = Double.toString(doubleAnswer1);

    TextView textAnswer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    textAnswer.setText(stringAnswer);
}
```

However I don't know how to write the code for the swipe events. I was thinking of multiple if conditions like:

```
if((doubleAnswer1 > doubleAnswer2) && (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN = true)){
        //create new equation
        }
```

And for every other possibilty (doubleAnswer1 < doubleAnswer2) as well if the MotionEvent was made the wrong direction. 
I tried to do it that way but it didn't work, so I don't know what to try out now. Maybe someone has an idea how to solve this.

If anything is unclear in my question, feel free to ask and I will try to clarify the problem :)

Thank you already in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use [GestureDetector](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html#detect) to detect it:

To detect a vertical swipe you could use this code:

```
class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener 
{            
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) 
    { 
        Log.d(TAG,"onDown: " + event.toString()); 
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent start, MotionEvent finish, float velocityX, float velocityY) 
    {
        if (start.getRawY() < finish.getRawY()) {
            //down
        } else {
            //up
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do I use this for my code if doubleAnswer1 > doubleAnswer2 or the other way round?

Comment: This code is to detect what the user has done, you have to set that to your textViews, and, in the OnFling method you do your checks to see if it's correct or not.